# Find all commits that changed a given directory from Java

Tags: java, jgit

I write a Java program, and I use jgit. In this Java program, I want to list all commits of some git repository `g` that changed at least one file in a directory `x`.

I do not want to solve the problem "on command line", but within Java.

Comment: interesting question, 1+; but what did you try? It might be easier to think in reverse, like how would you solve that with plain command line and then reverse engineer to jgit

Comment: jgit is still a bit of a mystery to me. I tried to find information about changed files in RevCommit, and I also tried to google this, but had the impression that trying to list all changed files etc. is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

In the high-level API of JGit you can use [Git.log()](https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/6.3.0.202209071007-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/Git.html#log()) with "addPath" to get a simple list of related commits.

```
   logs = git.log()
            .addPath("pom.xml")
            .call();
```

See this [snippet](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowLog.java#L99) in the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) for a ready-to-run example.

In general the methods on the entry-class [Git](https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/6.3.0.202209071007-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/Git.html) provide similar functionality to the regular git commands.

---

For the low-level API which provides much more fine-grained control/results, you can use [Git.diff()](https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/6.3.0.202209071007-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/Git.html#diff()) with "newTree" and "oldTree" and a "pathFilter". The trees are constructed via [RevWalk](https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/6.3.0.202209071007-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevWalk.html) and [CanonicalTreeParser](https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/6.3.0.202209071007-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/treewalk/CanonicalTreeParser.html)

There is a related snippet for this approach in the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) at [ShowFileDiff.java](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowFileDiff.java)